# NoClassDefFoundError with Ionic + Angular app in Android Studio

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am writing an ionic + angular app.

When I run it as a web app (`ionic serve`), the app works fine & no errors are displayed in the console.

Now I am trying to debug the app as an Android app.

`ionic capacitor run android -l` opens the app in Android studio, & the app opens & works as expected in the emulator.

But if I open the Android Studio console, I get the following error:

> I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;

Can someone please tell me why this error is occuring, & how I can resolve it?

Also, I can post code if that helps.

Comment: That’s a bug on the android support libraries, but shouldn’t affect your app

Answer (score 0):

remove android platform and add it again

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does it matter if I am using capacitor to run?

Comment: No it doesn’t matter

Comment: I've tried to run your second line, but now I get the following error: `npm ERR! Could not install from "android" as it does not contain a package.json file.`

Comment: Do you delete your package json file

Comment: That’s for cordova, not for capacitor, the answer is wrong